# What does this SSIS package data conversion error mean?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, type-conversion

> [Data Conversion [2]] Error: "Failed to convert data when converting LONGITUDE column (103) to" LONGITUDE copy "column (39). This conversion returned the status value 2 and the status text "The value could not be converted due to a potential loss of data. ".
>   "
>
> [Data Conversion [2]] Error: "SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. The "Data conversion.Output [Data conversion output] .Columns [Copy of LONGITUDE]" object failed due to error code 0xC020907F. Additionally, the error line layout on "Data Conversion. Output [Data Output Data] .Columns [LONGITUDE Copy]" specifies a failure on the error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component. Error messages can be sent beforehand with information indicating the reason for the failure.
>   "

How can I correct it . I have tried changing data types and matching them .
I have checked my EXCEL file for syntax error ... nothing

Comment: what is the source type and converted type?

Comment: DT_NUMERIC (18.14)

Comment: no need to convert if you did not change the data type

Comment: @SonaLegends you need to provide more details? what is the source column data type , the destination column data type? data source type? data destination type?

Comment: Fixed it but I have INPUT ERRORS in the destination now

Comment: ERROR CODE : 0x80040E2F

Comment: ERROR CODE : 0xC0209029

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `Data Conversion` transformation? If so, open it, and check the type of `Copy of Longitude`, compare that with source. Those two data type are not compatible. You could try to convert it to `double`.

If it is `EXCEL destination`, you need to convert it to `DT_WSTR`

Comment: I have ! both DT_NUMERIC (18.14)

Comment: why you need to convert it if they are both `DT_NUMERIC (18.14)`

Comment: I changed the source to DT_NUMERIC (18.14) to match the destination .

Comment: The Alias [Copy of LONGITUDE] type at least that I used in the mapping with the destination

Comment: what is your destination? excel destination? excel destination only accepts `DT_WSTR`

Comment: DB OLE destination

Answer (score 0):

you need to double all sizes in "data conversion" ,

first go to "source destination" and mark all nvarchar column

second go "data conversion" go to these columns and make it double size from length

Note : a data conversion by default make every column datatype 50